# How to parse to directory or collection from an horizontal clipboard text in Visual Basic (VS 2017)?

Tags: parsing, dictionary

I have something copied in clipboard that looks like this:

```
ID     Name     Last Name    Type     DOB          Payment
123    Joe          Doe       N     05-15-75         500
```

Need to assign the below values to variables?

I tried this:

```
Dim firstclipboardtext As String
firstclipboardtext = My.Computer.Clipboard.GetText
Dim firstdictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
if firstdictionary.contains("a") then
     id = "b" (which would be the value of the a key)
end if
```

Comment: clipboard text looks like this:                                                                            ID   Name Last Name Type DOB Payment and then below the values 
123     Joe Doe N 05-15-75 500 they fit perfectly in excel.

Comment: likely there is a \n in the text. which means new line.
you need to split it into two variables based on that